# PHP curl_multi impact on apache MPM Workers

Tags: php, apache, curl-multi

From apache library:

*Worker MPM (uses multiple child processes that can have multiple threads each. Each thread handles one connection at a time)
Prefork MPM (uses multiple child processes with one thread each. Each process handles one connection at a time)*

PHP multi_curl allows the processing of multiple cURL handles asynchronously.
What impact does it have on Apache MPM workers (both modes Worker and Prefork). Does Apache open new MPM worker per each outgoing curl_multi handle?

hypothetical example: PHP curl_multi will create 100 asynchronous connections to 100 different servers. Consume it 100 Apache MPM workers or just One?

Comment: You are curl'ing to 100 seperate servers (other servers-not yours). So each server will have 1 connetion FROM your script. It sounds like you think using curl_multi will effect YOUR Apache. You are connecting to other peoples Servers and the Apache (maybe) on those servers